# Execute a recipe only if prerequisities were created by previous recipe

Tags: makefile

I have the following line in my makefile:

```
$(SEGDIR)/%_seg.pdb: $(FASTADIR)/%.fasta $(PDBS)/%_nogaps.pdb
```

Each of the above prerequisites ($(FASTADIR)/%.fasta , $(PDBS)/%_nogaps.pdb) has its own recipe.
However, if one of the **inputs** to the recipe that creates the **fasta** file has an error, the file is not generated.

Is there any way to skip a target if it's corresponding prerequisites were not created in one of the prerequisite rules?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "skip a target".  Every prerequisite that is out of date has its recipe invoked to build it.  If the recipe fails, then the prerequisite fails to build.  If the prerequisite fails to build, then any target that depends on it won't be built either, and the make program will, ultimately, fail.  So no target will be built if any of its prerequisites failed to build.

Comment: What I'm asking is - is there a way to config make to skip the target instead of failing altogether if one of the prerequisites failed?

Comment: Well, it _will_ "skip the target" in that it won't try to build the target if the prerequisite fails.  If what you want is for make to continue trying to build other targets that don't rely on the failed prerequisite, rather than failing immediately, you can run `make` with the `-k` (keep going) option.  If what you want is for make to not fail at all even if something it tried to build fails, then no, there's no direct way to do that.  What you can do is invoke a sub-make to build those targets and prefix the sub-make with the `-` special character to ignore any failures there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what would you suggest if I have a list of files, that needs to be filtered with a specific condition? (and only those who pass the filter, should continue to the next rule)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand what you want to do so I can't give you advice.  What kind of "condition" do you mean?  Maybe it helps to think of it like this: `make` works by first building a directed graph of dependency relationships, then it walks that graph.  It is not possible to modify the structure of that graph at all while walking it, once it's been created.

Comment: A typical scenario would be something like this: I have many files containing protein structures. I want to process only a subset that fulfills a certain condition

That more or less answers my question, I guess.

I ended splitting the makefile into separate makefiles and currently, it is a reasonable solution

Comment: OK.  You still didn't answer my question about what kind of "condition" you mean.  Make works on file existence and file modification times.  It's a tool for detecting "out of date" conditions.  If the "condition" you are talking about is something different than that, or can't be reduced to that, then make isn't going to align well with what you want to do.  You'll have to, as you did, detect the condition some other way then invoke make only on the files that meet the condition.